# Which hosting provider supports Haskell?

Tags: haskell, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have a hosting account with GoDaddy, but it does not support Haskell.

Comment: @Matt I know, right? Anything beyond HTML/PHP and you're S.O.L.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend amazon web services, $15/month for a micro instance for testing/devel, and the costs go up from there depending on your needs.  For the love of all that is good and wonderful in this universe, however, do *not* use godaddy for anything but SSL certificates and domain names.  This just seems like an absolutely horrible idea.  They're just not the kinda people you want to work with on things like that.

As alternative VPS providers go, there are slicehost, linode, rackspace cloud, and I'm sure some others too.  In my experience with rackspace cloud, slicehost, and AWS, AWS has been best by far.

Answer (score 6):

[NearlyFreeSpeech](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/) is a web hosting provider that supports Haskell as CGI language ([list of languages supported](http://example.nfshost.com/versions.php)).

I'm hosting my personal webpage with them, although I don't have experience with the CGI part, because my site is entirely static.

Answer (score 4):

GHC compiles Haskell code to a UNIX executable, so anything that can run an arbitrary executable file and has some kind of front-facing server (e.g. nginx with mod_proxy) capable of proxying to your Haskell process is all you need.

Comment: Thanks. Uhmmm.. Does that mean Godaddy can work?

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning anything serious that is a little non-standard, get a VPS somewhere. It’s ~350$/year and you have a little virtual machine on which your are alone and you are root

Comment: Yes, I am planning a commercial website.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I see GoDaddy does offer virtual private servers.

Comment: Slicehost and Gandi are good VPS hosts.